# How to use awk or sed to combine match content from two files

Tags: awk, sed

I have two file, file1 and file2
I need to search file2 with each line of file1, and put them together in another form once match
my progress:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{ids[$0]=$0;next}{for(id in ids){if($0 ~ "\\y"id"\\y"){print "- name:"id; print "  version: " ; print}}}' file1 file2
```

**file1:**

```
attr-2.4.48
bzip2-1.0.8
curl-7.71.1
dnsmasq-2.86
dropbear-2022.82
elfutils-0.179
ethtool-5.4
```

**file2:**

```
  url: https://sourceforge.net/projects/lzmautils/files/xz-5.2.5.tar.gz/download
  url: http://download.savannah.nongnu.org/releases/attr/attr-2.4.48.tar.gz
  url: https://sourceware.org/pub/bzip2/bzip2-1.0.8.tar.gz
  url: https://curl.se/download/curl-7.71.1.tar.bz2
  url: https://sourceware.org/elfutils/ftp/0.179/elfutils-0.179.tar.bz2
  url: https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/network/ethtool/ethtool.git/snapshot/ethtool-5.4.tar.gz
```

**output**

```
- name: attr
  version: 2.4.48
  url: http://download.savannah.nongnu.org/releases/attr/attr-2.4.48.tar.gz
- name: bzip2
  version: 1.0.8
  url: https://sourceware.org/pub/bzip2/bzip2-1.0.8.tar.gz
- name: curl
  version: 7.71.1
  url: https://curl.se/download/curl-7.71.1.tar.bz2
- name: dnsmasq
  version: 2.86
  url:
- name: dropbear
  version: 2022.82
  url:
- name: elfutils
  version: 0.179
  url: https://sourceware.org/elfutils/ftp/0.179/elfutils-0.179.tar.bz2
- name: ethtool
  version: 5.4
  url: https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/network/ethtool/ethtool.git/snapshot/ethtool-5.4.tar.gz
```

Comment: There are four correct answers below, and I can only check one from them. They are all great answer, please refer them as your preference

Comment: I guess just run a benchmark by running these solutions on a very large dataset and see which one is producing fast results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sed 'h;s/-/\n  version: /;s/^/- name: /p;g;s/-.*//;s/^/grep /;s/$/ file2/e' file1 | sed 's/^$/  url:/'`

- use sed to `h` hold the original fine from file1
- `s/-/\n  version: /;s/^/- name:/p` print version/name
- `g` get the original line again
- `s/^/grep /;s/$/ file2/e` used `s///e` to create a grep command and execute it
- `| sed 's/^$/  url:/'` clean up empty lines

Basically looping over the lines of `file1` with sed, calling grep with `s///e`.

Answer (score 2):

This `awk` should work for you with 2 different field separators for 2 input files:

```bash
awk '
FNR == NR {
   u = $0
   sub(/(\.[a-z][[:alnum:]]*)+(\/[^\/]+)?$/, "")
   a[$NF] = u
   next
}
{
   print "- name:", $1
   print "  version:", $2
   print "  " ($0 in a ? a[$0] : "url:")
}' FS='/' file2 FS='-' file1
```

**Output:**

```bash
- name: attr
  version: 2.4.48
  url: http://download.savannah.nongnu.org/releases/attr/attr-2.4.48.tar.gz
- name: bzip2
  version: 1.0.8
  url: https://sourceware.org/pub/bzip2/bzip2-1.0.8.tar.gz
- name: curl
  version: 7.71.1
  url: https://curl.se/download/curl-7.71.1.tar.bz2
- name: dnsmasq
  version: 2.86
  url:
- name: dropbear
  version: 2022.82
  url:
- name: elfutils
  version: 0.179
  url: https://sourceware.org/elfutils/ftp/0.179/elfutils-0.179.tar.bz2
- name: ethtool
  version: 5.4
  url: https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/network/ethtool/ethtool.git/snapshot/ethtool-5.4.tar.gz
```

Comment: url is duplicated

Comment: What do you mean by `url is duplicated`? Which part of shown output is not matching with your expected output?

Answer (score 2):

What you want can be done naturally in a small shell script using `cut` and `grep`.

We can use `sed` instead of the `cut` and `grep` combo and get a shell script like this:

```
cat "file1" | while read prginfo
do
    name="${prginfo%%-*}"
    version="${prginfo##*-}"
    url="$(sed -n "/${prginfo}/ {s/url: //;p}" file2)"
    printf -- "- name: %s\n  version: %s\n  url: %s\n" "$name" "$version" "$url" 
done
```

We loop over the lines of file1 (due to the `cat`, `|` and `while read`).

The name and version parts are parsed from the lines of file1 via *shell parameter expansion* .

The url is parsed via `sed`:

- `-n` is used to suppress output from unmatched lines
- `/${prginfo}/` is used to match the line and apply the further sed sommands inside the braches:

  - `s/url: //;p}` replaces the "url: " and prints the modified line
- we could replace this line with `url=$(grep "$prginfo" "$2" | cut -d\  -f2)`

This is a bit shorter than first reading and storing the file2. But it might take much longer if those files are large.

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples only, in GNU `awk` please try following `awk` code; written and tested in GNU `awk` should work in any version of it.

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  arr1[$1]=$2
  next
}
{
  for(i in arr1){
    if(index($0,i)){
      arr2[i]
      print "- name: " i ORS "  version: " arr1[i] ORS  $0
      break;
    }
  }
}
END{
  for(i in arr1){
    if(!(i in arr2)){
      print "- name: " i ORS "  version: " arr1[i] ORS "  url:"
    }
  }
}
' FS="-" file1 file2
```

Comment: it's logical and very clear to read, thanks!